# xenial - s390x missing grub/grub2 packages?

Tags: package-management

Folks,

I am trying to "apt-get install grub (or grub2)" on s390x architecture but it is unable to find this package.  Please let me know how I can access it or any workaround that may exist.

Thanks.

Comment: It appears that the `grub` package is not available for s390x architecture at the moment. See http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=s390x&searchon=names&keywords=grub for a list of "grub" packages on that architecture -- perhaps the `grub-disk` package would be of interest?
 I wish I could help you more, but I'm no expert with grub or s390x.